# Is there a way to change my Traditional Slack App icon using an API or SDK?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I want to be able to update my Traditional Slack App icon in a programmatically way, either by calling an API or using an SDK.

I verified the [App Manifest API](https://api.slack.com/reference/manifests), and it's possible to update the App name, Long and Short description, but there's no support for the icon.

After spending some time reading the documentation, I found that updating the app icon this way is apparently possible under the [New Modular Apps](https://api.slack.com/future/manifest).

Is there any workaround or other way to update my Traditional App Icon using another SDK/API?

I'm aware that I can change my bot icon in messages using the chat.postMessage if I have the chat:write.customize scope, and this is not what I want, I want to update the App/Bot Icon on the workspace where it's installed or all workspaces.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to update your app's icon programmatically with the Slack API. It can only be done manually from your app settings page.